# How come this code gets an NPE?

Tags: java

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home/Downloads"));
```

How come this code gets an NPE error?

I know it returns null, but the directory is there...

Comment: Focus on the real issue, which would be why does `new File` get passed null. It makes for a [very] slightly better question: e.g. "Why does System.getProperty return null?" Asking *why* XYZ causes an NPE is rarely a "good" question - non searchable and too localized in most cases.

Answer (score 6):

because

```
System.getProperty("user.home/Downloads")
```

returns `null`, because there is no such propery set with key `user.home/Downloads`

You may be looking for

```
final String fileName = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.saperator + "Downloads";
File f = new File(fileName);
```

Comment: I know that, but why? The file is there
EDIT: thanks

Comment: @ZachFollette: Because there is no such property. Period.

Comment: Yeah, I just find that weird, because if I do System.out.println(filename); it prints out C:/Users/Zach/Downloads

Comment: @ZachFollette Which filename are you printing? If the above line is resulting into NPE, how are you getting filename?

Comment: System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));

Answer (score 0):

Properties are collections of `<key,value>` pairs (both Strings) that can give you information about some predefined system attributes. Which ones are predefined is listed in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29) of the function `System.getProperties`. The following keys are defined:

```
java.version
java.vendor 
java.vendor.url 
java.home 
java.vm.specification.version 
java.vm.specification.vendor 
java.vm.specification.name 
java.vm.version 
java.vm.vendor 
java.vm.name 
java.specification.version 
java.specification.vendor 
java.specification.name 
java.class.version 
java.class.path 
java.library.path 
java.io.tmpdir 
java.compiler 
java.ext.dirs 
os.name 
os.arch 
os.version 
file.separator 
path.separator 
line.separator 
user.name 
user.home 
user.dir
```

As you can see `user.home` is in that list, that's why it works perfectly fine to call `System.getProperty("user.home");`.

However, you are calling the `getProperty` method with the argument `user.home/Downloads` -- this is an undefined key, as it is not on the above list.

If you want to append `"/Downloads"` to the user's home directory, you have to do it *outside the `getProperty` call*:

```
System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Downloads";
```

This way, you're using a defined key and won't get a `NullPointerException`.